# Redirect loop from login script dilemma

Tags: php, loops, redirect, authentication

I have come across an issue with a login script which I have never seen before, and need some help solving it.

I have the following php files:

1. index.php
2. signIn.php

In **index.php**, there is a login form which is directed to **signIn.php** in order to validate the users information. As long as the user's credentials are correct, it redirects the user back to **index.php** and echos the users **username**.

*Problem 1*

If the user is not logged in, the part of **index.php** which is supposed to echo the username displays the following error:

> Undefined index: username in index.php on line 26

To solve this, I added the following PHP to **index.php** - assuming it would help find the undefined index:

```
include 'signIn.php';
```

*Problem 2*

The include causes a redirect loop, and doesn't allow users to sign in. How can I redirect back to **index.php** when the user logs in whilst also using include **signIn.php**?

---

index.php (stripped down)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'signIn.php';
?>
<head>
    Blah blah
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <?php
            if($_SESSION["username"]) {
                echo $_SESSION["username"];
            } else {
                echo "Guest";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <form action="signIn.php" method="POST">
        <h1>Sign in</h1>
        <?php if($message!="") { echo $message; } ?>
        <input type="email" name="username">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign in">
    </form>
</body>
```

signIn.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $message="";
    if(count($_POST)>0) {

        $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","blah","blah");
        mysql_select_db("blah",$conn);

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and Password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");

        $row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        if(is_array($row)) {
            $_SESSION["username"] = $row["UserName"];
        } else {
            $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
        header("Location:index.php");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether the `$_SESSION['username']` is set yet:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) {
    // Hi user!
}
```

And for problem 2, you only want to include `signIn` if the opposite of the above condition is true:

```
if (! isset($_SESSION['username']) {
    // Redirect the user
}
```

Comment: You're probably calling `session_start` twice.

Answer (score 0):

you need  to use $_POST super global to get the value of user name as you used post method.

like so ,

```
  $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
```

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   Header("Location: signin.php");
   exit(0);
}
```

signin.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(count($_POST)>0) {
           // do auth here
           ## Beware of your mysql code which is sensible to sql injection.
           //
           if ($AUTHOK) {
               header("Location:index.php");
               exit(0);
           }
    }

?>
... html code ...
```